# File received from socket is missing when run on Android

Tags: android, sockets, file-transfer

I am building an android app, we build a socket to transfer file from this end to another end.
The file is sent through computer (when we test it on the computer), it works very well.
But when we build app to android, and send file from this android to another android through the socket that we put on a computer (used as server) so the received file is missing (file size is not enough). Sometime it is enough, but sometime is not enough, but almost time it is NOT enough.

It totally works very well on PC when testing.

Hope you guys have some ideas to help me.

This is my code:

1/ Code at Java server application - send file:

```
int countBufferReceive = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
int numByte = 0;
while ((numByte = this.receiveStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
    client.sendStream.write(buffer, 0, numByte);
    client.sendStream.flush();

    countBufferReceive += numByte;
    if (countBufferReceive == fileLength)
        break;
}
```

2/ Code at Android app - receive file:

```
int countBufferReceive = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
int numByte = 0;
while ((numByte = ConnectServer.receiveStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
    fos.write(buffer, 0, numByte);
    fos.flush();

    countBufferReceive += numByte;
    if (countBufferReceive == fileLength)
        break;
}
fos.close();
```

Thank you,

Comment: Post your android code.. And how many times have you successfully recieved files on android?

Comment: How about showing some code of what you're doing?

Comment: Yes, I just added some code, hope you can help.

Comment: Is filleLength the same value on both the server and the phone?

Comment: Is filleLength the same value on both the server and the phone?
=> Yes.